# Will published message with subscriber be persisted in the queue?

Tags: rebus

I just did a quick test and seem that the published messages with bus.Publish does not get persisted in msmq until it has a subscriber.

1. Did I do something wrong in the configuration?
2. Is this by design? And Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how publish/subscribe works with MSMQ - when a publisher publishes a message, it will look for the queue names of the subscribers in its subscription storage, and send a copy of the message to each subscriber.

It follows from this that if there's no subscribers, then no messages are actually sent.

Logically, it works the same way when using multicast-capable transports like e.g. RabbitMQ - with RabbitMQ, then message will be published to the broker, which will then distribute a copy of the message to each subscriber - and again, if there are none, the message will no be delivered to anyone and thus cannot be seen anywhere.

I hope that makes sense :)